# Error: Password validation "reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java

//This program validates passwords, must have 8 characters, 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 digit, once the password is validated the program should include a method that asks the user to reenter the password to make sure they match if the passwords does not match the program will ask the user to reenter the password until they do. I'm getting a "reached end of file while parsing" error. 
Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PassChecker2 {

   public static void main (String [] args) {

      String inputPassword;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println(" Please enter your Password:");
      inputPassword = input.next();

      System.out.println(passminChecker(inputPassword));
      System.out.println("");

      main(args);


   }   
   public static boolean passminChecker(String password) 
   {

      if (password.length () > 7)
      {
          if(passminChecker(password))
      {
          return true;
      }
      else
      {
          return false;
      }
     }
      else
      {

      System.out.println("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");
      return false;
      }

    }

   public static boolean checkerPass(String password)
   {

      boolean hasUpperCase = false;
      boolean hasLowerCase = false;
      boolean hasDigit = false;
      char c;
      for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
      {
          c = password.charAt(i);

          if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
          {
             hasUpperCase = true;
          }
          else if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
          {
             hasLowerCase = true;
          }
          else if(Character.isDigit(c))
          {
             hasDigit = false;
          }
          if(hasUpperCase && hasLowerCase && hasDigit)
          {
               return true;
          }
      else
      {

      System.out.println("Password is invalid must meet all requiremennts.");
      return false;
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: I suppose it's the compiler that's complaining. There's a closing bracket missing at the end. Please use correct indent!!

Comment: By then way: your `main` method is calling itself with no condition. Same problem within the `passminChecker` method.

Comment: Your `checkerPass` method is never called.

Comment: And probably need to set hasDigit to true if Character.isDigit(c) is met

Answer (score 0):

That error most often occurs when you have an unclosed block in your code. You're missing a `}` at the end of the class. This will be easier to spot yourself if you're more consistent with where you put your opening and closing curly brackets. Put them either all on their own line, or all on the same line as the code that starts the block.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PassChecker2 {

   public static void main (String [] args) {

      String inputPassword;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println(" Please enter your Password:");
      inputPassword = input.next();

      System.out.println(passminChecker(inputPassword));
      System.out.println("");

      main(args);


   }   
   public static boolean passminChecker(String password) {

      if (password.length () > 7) {
          if(passminChecker(password)) {
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
     } else {
          System.out.println("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");
          return false;
     }
    }
   public static boolean checkerPass(String password) {

      boolean hasUpperCase = false;
      boolean hasLowerCase = false;
      boolean hasDigit = false;
      char c;
      for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
          c = password.charAt(i);

          if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
             hasUpperCase = true;
          } else if(Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
             hasLowerCase = true;
          } else if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
             hasDigit = false;
          }
          if(hasUpperCase && hasLowerCase && hasDigit) {
               return true;
          } else {
              System.out.println("Password is invalid must meet all requiremennts.");
              return false;
          }
     }
    }
}//this is the one that was missing
```